# Node JS Module, How can I use local function in module

Tags: node.js, express, module

I'm wondering how can I access local function in my module.

**In calc module :**

```
var calc = {};
calc.add = function(a,b){
    return a+b;
};

calc.multi = function(a,b){
    return a*b;
};

module.exports = calc;
```

However If I add some function use a local function like this :

```
calc.verify = function(a,b){
    return (this.add(a,b)) + (this.multi(a,b))
};
```

This is not working properly.
I'd like to use both calc.add and calc.multi function at any time in my module.

What's wrong in my code?

Edit ::

```
var calc = {};
calc.add = function(a,b){
    return a+b;
};

calc.multi = function(a,b){
    return a*b;
};

calc.verify = function(a,b){
    return (this.add(a,b)) + (this.multi(a,b))
};

module.exports = calc;
```

Comment: Depending on how verify is called, `this` might not be the `calc` object. Try s/this/calc/

Comment: How are you requiring the module and calling `verify()`? A sample code of that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are calling `verify()`.

Supposing your module is called `calc.js`, this should work:

```
const calc = require('./calc');
console.log(calc.verify(1,2));
```

This does not work:

```
const calc = require('./calc');
const verify = calc.verify;
console.log(verify(1,2));
```

Nor this:

```
const { verify } = require('./calc')
console.log(verify(1, 2));
```

The reason is that if you call `verify()` as an unbound function, `this` will become undefined. If for some reason you want to call `verify()` as an unbound function, you can use `bind()`:

```
const calc = require('./calc');
const verify = calc.verify.bind(calc);
console.log(verify(1,2));
```

Other way would be rewriting your `calc.js` module without using `this`:

```
calc.verify = function(a,b){
    return (calc.add(a,b)) + (calc.multi(a,b))
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Perfect!! :)